# I get an empty column when I return the film title

Tags: sql, postgresql

```
SELECT film.title
FROM rental
INNER JOIN film ON rental.last_update = film.last_update
WHERE return_date BETWEEN '2005-05-29' AND '2005-05-30'
```

I was expecting to get back the title of films within specified dates, despite I am making a join between two tables film and rental who has in common `last_update` column

Comment: because you inner join, there needs to be a match on your film table. If there's no match, (which seems like its the case) then you won't get any results. If you change your FROM to film and LEFT JOIN on rental, you'll see results for title despite no match on your join

Comment: last_update seems to be an odd way to join. Any film_id column?

Comment: but last_update is a common column between the two tables I still do not understand why I can not perform join using last_update?

Comment: i tried left join, then it gives back all values are null in the title coloumn

Comment: could it be the reason because maybe last_update does not have values for all films? maybe only few ??

Answer (score 0):

If my intuition is right then I thin rental table must have film_id column on something referencing to film table.

It will be nice if you could give us  ddl-s of this tables